# How do I allocate a keyboard to a specific app

Tags: keyboard, applescript, developer-program

I'm searching for an app or script that would allow me to have two keyboards connected to my Mac.
One would be for normal usage and the other one should be allocated to a specific app. I think it could be very handy especially if you have to change between different apps all the time and don't want to use cmd + tab.

I often have to watch videos and like many others I control them via "Video speed controller" which allows me to advance, rewind, pause, increase and decrease speed and many more. Likewise, I thought about getting a "half keyboard" with which this could be possible and also pretty cheap.

Is there any chance to make this happen?

Comment: Any app should respond to whichever keyboard you are pressing the keys on.  Is there some reason this does not just work for your specific use case?  Or is the idea that when you touch your extra keyboard a specific app should be launched?

Comment: @TomGewecke - I'm seeing this more as a 'is there some way to have one input device  which is targeted to some function on some app no matter what else I'm doing - ie, not the front-most app]. I think the answer is, 'no'.

Comment: You might have a look at Karabiner -Elements which clearly differentiates several keyboards – BUT I'm not sure whether it recognises using several ones AT ONCE. url: https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org